# Launching apps made with Air for Android stand alone

Tags: adobe-flash-cs3, animate-cc

Do Air for Android apps need Adobe Air to be pre-installed on the device to run?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on your publish settings.
you can embed the AIR runtime with your app so users won't need to install it.
but you must consider that it will add about 12-13 mb to the size of your app.